# SQL Query : Get only non duplicated column in raw

Tags: sql, teradata

I try to do a query on a table like this:

[image]

I need to have the only column that don't duplicate in the row, in the example below I need only : **15** for the first line and **45** for the second, and if I have multiple unique variables, I need to have them all like **1,1,2,2,3,4,5** I want **3,4,5**

That any one of you have an idea how do I could do this in sql? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have only that 5 columns in table? What value you wants in column in case of duplicate... NULL?

Comment: You could normalize the schema. Then it would be a quite simple query With `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*) = 1`.

Comment: What if there are multiple unique values in a row: `1,1,2,3,4´?

Comment: This table is really bad designed. Please normalize it like Paul said.

Comment: MySQL or Teradata?

Comment: Fix the structure of your table.  This will only give you problems later on.  A very simple query like this is so hard because the table structure is messed up.

Comment: I just edit it @PaulSpiegel , like i said i need to have all the unique variables in the schema , and I could have Null :(

Comment: @Andrew Teradata

Answer (score 0):

A Standard SQL Select specifies the columns you want to retrieve, so I don't see how a standard select could be used to extract the data directly.

So how would we do it?

I think the 'SQL' way would be to create a table (which could be a temporary table) and insert into that the values we want to return.

In your example (I suspect real life is significantly more complicated) then we would create a table with two colums 'ID' And 'UniqueOp';  As there could be more than one unique operator in any row you would not want to make either of these a primary key, but we could make both the primary key (as if Op is duplicated it won't be unique).

Then populate the table with selects.

```sql
DROP TABLE tblResults IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE tblResults(ID Int(11) NOT NULL, UniqueOp INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY(ID, UniqueOp));

INSERT INTO tblResults(ID, UniqueOp) (SELECT ID, Op_1 FROM tblBase WHERE Op_1<>Op_2 AND Op_1<>Op_3 AND Op_1<>Op_4 AND Op_1<>Op_5);
INSERT INTO tblResults(ID, UniqueOp) (SELECT ID, Op_2 FROM tblBase WHERE Op_2<>Op_1 AND Op_2<>Op_3 AND Op_2<>Op_4 AND Op_2<>Op_5);
INSERT INTO tblResults(ID, UniqueOp) (SELECT ID, Op_3 FROM tblBase WHERE Op_3<>Op_1 AND Op_3<>Op_2 AND Op_3<>Op_4 AND Op_3<>Op_5);
INSERT INTO tblResults(ID, UniqueOp) (SELECT ID, Op_4 FROM tblBase WHERE Op_4<>Op_1 AND Op_4<>Op_2 AND Op_4<>Op_3 AND Op_4<>Op_5);
INSERT INTO tblResults(ID, UniqueOp) (SELECT ID, Op_5 FROM tblBase WHERE Op_5<>Op_1 AND Op_5<>Op_2 AND Op_5<>Op_3 AND Op_5<>Op_4);

SELECT ID, UniqueOp FROM tblResults;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select id, op
from ((select id, op_1 as op, 1 as ind from t) union all
      (select id, op_2 as op, 2 as ind from t) union all
      (select id, op_3 as op, 3 as ind from t) union all
      (select id, op_4 as op, 4 as ind from t) union all
      (select id, op_5 as op, 5 as ind from t) 
     ) t
group by id, op
having count(*) = 1;
```

You can also do this with a massive `case`.  Assuming you have no `null` values:

```
select id,
       (case when op1 not in (op2, op3, op4, op5) then op1
             when op2 not in (op1, op3, op4, op5) then op2
             when op3 not in (op1, op2, op4, op5) then op3
             when op4 not in (op1, op2, op3, op5) then op4
             when op5 not in (op1, op2, op3, op4) then op5
        end) as unique_op
from t;
```

Comment: the only option when the data is denormalized in such a way that rows become columns.  Of course, the query doesn't scale as the number of columns increases; that's why all the sql folks are so obsessed with normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the option below as per your requirement-

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN op_1 NOT IN (op_2,op_3,op_4,op_5) THEN op_1 ELSE NULL END op_1,
CASE WHEN op_2 NOT IN (op_1,op_3,op_4,op_5) THEN op_2 ELSE NULL END op_2,
CASE WHEN op_3 NOT IN (op_1,op_2,op_4,op_5) THEN op_3 ELSE NULL END op_3,
CASE WHEN op_4 NOT IN (op_1,op_2,op_3,op_5) THEN op_4 ELSE NULL END op_4,
CASE WHEN op_5 NOT IN (op_1,op_2,op_3,op_4) THEN op_5 ELSE NULL END op_5
FROM your_table
```

Output is-

```
ID      op_1    op_2    op_3    op_4    op_5
12345                                   15
12346                   45
```

Or option -2

```
SELECT ID,op_1 AS VALUE
FROM your_table WHERE op_1 NOT IN (op_2,op_3,op_4,op_5)

UNION ALL

SELECT ID,op_2 AS VALUE
FROM your_table WHERE op_2 NOT IN (op_1,op_3,op_4,op_5)

UNION ALL

SELECT ID,op_3 AS VALUE
FROM your_table WHERE op_3 NOT IN (op_1,op_2,op_4,op_5)

UNION ALL

SELECT ID,op_4 AS VALUE
FROM your_table WHERE op_4 NOT IN (op_1,op_2,op_3,op_5)

UNION ALL

SELECT ID,op_5 AS VALUE
FROM your_table WHERE op_5 NOT IN (op_1,op_2,op_3,op_4)
```

Output is-

```
ID      VALUE
12346   45
12345   15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Teradata specific answer using [unpivot](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/WJrLnu1S40wwlDNGkFQc5w)

```
 select
    id,
    op_val
from
    <your table>
UNPIVOT ((op_val) for (op_type) in (op_1,op_2,op_3,op_4,op_5)) t
qualify  (count (*) over (partition by id,op_val) ) = 1
```

Less verbose than a bunch of case statements or unions, although unpivot is a little confusing to use.  If you just run

```
select
*
from
<your table>
UNPIVOT ((op_val) for (op_type) in (op_1,op_2,op_3,op_4,op_5)) t
```

it's a little clearer.  The 5 op* columns become op_type, and the values in the op* columns become op_val.

Answer (score 0):

This will handle `null` values:

```
select
    id,
    trim(trailing ',' from concat(
        case when op1 in (op2, op3, op4, op5)
             then null else cast(op1 as varchar) + ',' end,
        case when op2 in (op1, op3, op4, op5)
             then null else cast(op2 as varchar) + ',' end,
        case when op3 in (op1, op2, op4, op5)
             then null else cast(op3 as varchar) + ',' end,
        case when op4 in (op1, op2, op3, op5)
             then null else cast(op4 as varchar) + ',' end,
        case when op5 in (op1, op2, op3, op4)
             then null else cast(op5 as varchar) + ',' end
        )
    )
from t;
```

You can't use `not in` when the list contains `null` values but you can effectively reverse the logic via the `case when <opX is dup> then null else <opX> end`.

Here's a sample running against SQL Server. (Note that it doesn't handle the trailing comma.
https://rextester.com/POYXO56613